# Find the most common sub string in factorized/grouped character vector and assign to factor/group

Tags: r, string, text, character

My initial data set consists of three columns and looks like this:

> data

```
                        Item  GroupNo GroupDescr
MELON-HONEYDEWS-LARGE 1 EACH 23385780        TBD
MELON-HONEYDEWS SMALL 1 EACH 23385780        TBD
MELON-HONEYDEWS-LARGE 1 EACH 23385780        TBD
MELON-HONEYDEWS SMALL 1 EACH 23385780        TBD
   ORANGES-NAVEL-MEDIUM 1 LB  9214140        TBD
    ORANGES-NAVEL-LARGE 1 LB  9214140        TBD
    ORANGES-NAVEL-SMALL 1 LB  9214140        TBD
   ORANGES-NAVEL-MEDIUM 1 LB  9214140        TBD
    ORANGES-NAVEL-LARGE 1 LB  9214140        TBD
    ORANGES-NAVEL-SMALL 1 LB  9214140        TBD
```

Objects in the **Item** character variable are grouped by the factor variable **GroupNo** and each group needs to be further described by another character variable **GroupDescr**.
The descriptor variable is to be determined.

I am looking for a function that

1. takes the factorized/grouped character vector **Item**,
2. finds its most common string such as *MELON-HONEYDEWS 1 EACH* (for the factor variable **GroupNo** = "23385780") or *ORANGES-NAVEL- 1 LB* (**GroupNo** = "9214140") and
3. writes the common string per group/factor in the variable **GroupDescr**.

Hence, the resulting data set should look like this:

> data

```
                        Item  GroupNo             GroupDescr
MELON-HONEYDEWS-LARGE 1 EACH 23385780 MELON-HONEYDEWS 1 EACH
MELON-HONEYDEWS SMALL 1 EACH 23385780 MELON-HONEYDEWS 1 EACH
MELON-HONEYDEWS-LARGE 1 EACH 23385780 MELON-HONEYDEWS 1 EACH
MELON-HONEYDEWS SMALL 1 EACH 23385780 MELON-HONEYDEWS 1 EACH
   ORANGES-NAVEL-MEDIUM 1 LB  9214140    ORANGES-NAVEL- 1 LB
    ORANGES-NAVEL-LARGE 1 LB  9214140    ORANGES-NAVEL- 1 LB
    ORANGES-NAVEL-SMALL 1 LB  9214140    ORANGES-NAVEL- 1 LB
   ORANGES-NAVEL-MEDIUM 1 LB  9214140    ORANGES-NAVEL- 1 LB
    ORANGES-NAVEL-LARGE 1 LB  9214140    ORANGES-NAVEL- 1 LB
    ORANGES-NAVEL-SMALL 1 LB  9214140    ORANGES-NAVEL- 1 LB
```

In reality, the character vector **Item** is much longer (length > 1000) and items are grouped by more than 200 factors of the **GroupNo** variable. Therefore, I look for an efficient text-mining function that can be applied per group/factor or that somehow loops through different groups/factors.

Answer (score 1):

In full generality, we're talking about the [Longest Common Subsequence Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem), which is non-trivial to implement.  I think the answer here is to look for a heuristic that is likely to satisfy most of your requirements.

I think, based on what you've shown, that extracting the maximum common **prefix** and **suffix** might be the answer here.

We can get the prefix with a helper function (adapted from [R: find largest common substring starting at the beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285010/r-find-largest-common-substring-starting-at-the-beginning))

```
lcprefix <- function(strs) {
  # Make sure we're getting strings, not factors
  strs <- as.character(strs)

  # Get the smallest length
  minlen <- min(nchar(strs))

  # Truncate them all to that length
  truncstr <- substr(strs, 1, minlen)

  # Get the raw character codes
  mat <- sapply(truncstr, charToRaw)

  # Find the rows that are identical
  diffs <- cumprod(apply(mat, 1, function(r) { length(unique(r)) == 1 }))

  # Re-ify the strings
  rawToChar(mat[as.logical(diffs), 1])
}
```

Then the chain becomes

```
> # Split the table
> df.split <- split(df, df$GroupNo)
> # Now, for each group, grab the prefix
> df.prefix <- lapply(df.split, function(d) { lcprefix(d$Item) })
> # And merge back in
> df$GroupDescr <- df.prefix[df$GroupNo]
```

Similar logic would apply to create an `lcsuffix` function to get the maximal suffix.

Answer (score 0):

You could use gsub with regular expressions

Assuming all the Item descriptions are similar, you could for instance use the following

```
    txt1 <- "ORANGES-NAVEL-MEDIUM 1 LB"
    gsub("(.*)-[a-zA-Z]*","\\1",txt1)
    [1] "ORANGES-NAVEL 1 LB"
```

Comment: Your function takes a single character value ("ORANGES-NAVEL-MEDIUM 1 LB") as an argument, but I am looking for a function that takes a multi-value character vector as an argument -- c("ORANGES-NAVEL-LARGE 1 LB", "ORANGES-NAVEL-MEDIUM 1 LB", "ORANGES-NAVEL-SMALL 1 LB") and finds the common sub-string that is part of every value in the character vector ("ORANGES-NAVEL- 1 LB").